# latin1_general_ci and charset ISO-8859-15

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I try to store strings of charset ISO-8859-15 in MySQL fields with `CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATION latin1_general_ci`.

It seems to be the case that both of them are not full compatible. I am not able to save a correct €-Sign.

Can anybody tell me the correct `CHARACTER SET` for ISO-8859-15?

Comment: read [this page](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18576)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15), there are 8 differences between ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-15.  The €-Sign is one of them.  I see on my copy of 5.6 a latin1 (ISO-8859-1) `CHARACTER SET`, but no latin9 (ISO-8859-15).

It is possible to [add your own character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-character-set.html) and collation to MySQL, but that may be more than you want to tackle.  There is a [Worklog](http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=4579) for adding it, but they need nudging to ever get it done.

Sorry.  Can you live with latin1 or latin2 (which has at least the Euro)?  Or, better yet, switch to utf8, which has all the characters, and a zillion more.

Comment: yes i miss latin9, too in my copy. I am struggeling with migrating to utf-8 but my project is so large. More than 100 tables in 5 DBs. It is hard but it seems to be the time to do it right now.

Comment: latin one has the euro but not at the right char for 8859-15.